# Is there a library in Dart to chart network graphs?

Tags: graphs, charts, dart

I am looking for a native way to draw network graphs in dart. Possibly with the ability to add edges and nodes on the fly.

Does something like Java's JUNG, Python's IGraph or JS's Sigma exists in Dart?

(this was originally posted on stackoverflow but was offtopic there)

Comment: Found something?

Comment: no, unfortunately :(

Comment: Just arrived back here. Still not, I suppose?